# ¿Cómo puedo agregar una cola de reproducción en mi comando play?

Tags: python, discord.py

Estoy haciendo un bot de discord dedicado a la reproducción de música, ya tengo el bot listo, **el único problema es que cuando el bot esta reproduciendo la música y agrego otra se detiene la música y no se reproduce la otra**.

Este es mi código:

```
@client.command()
async def play(ctx,*,search_v):
  
  query_string = parse.urlencode({'search_query': search_v})
  html_content = request.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string)
    # print(html_content.read().decode())
  search_results = re.findall( r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html_content.read().decode())
  url = "https://youtu.be/" + search_results[0]
    # I will put just the first result, you can loop the response to show more results
  
  
  ctx.voice_client.stop()
  FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {"before_options":"-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5","options":"-vn"}
  YDL_OPTIONS = {"format":"bestaudio"}
  vc = ctx.voice_client

  with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:

    info = ydl.extract_info(url,download=False)
    url2 = info["formats"][0]["url"]
    source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2,**FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
      
    vc.play(source)
    embed = discord.Embed( colour=discord.Colour.teal(),
      
    title="**Escuchando**", 
      description= ("El bot esta reproduciendo "+search_v+" :headphones: "))
    
    embed.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/yGpMoG9.gif")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

He estado buscando los últimos días y he encontrado esta [opción](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605422/discord-py-music-bot-how-to-combine-a-play-and-queue-command), mi problema es que **no sé cómo implementarlo a mi código**.

Comment: Discord emite un evento cuando la música termina, lo que tendrías que hacer es almacenar todas las canciones a reproducir en una lista y al momento de terminar la canción borras el primer elemento y luego reproduces el primer elemento

Comment: Y eso afectaria cuando este en mas de 2 servidores

Comment: Creo que si. Para ese caso usas un diccionario

Comment: Es que mi bot esta en 23 servidores entonces solo la cola faltaria

Comment: Un diccionario basta

Comment: Pero por ejemplo digamos cada servidor se haría un diccionario ?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129292/discussion-between-christian-and-pingui-maya).

Comment: No había necesidad de hacer esa edición y podría considerarse absurda, ya que no aporta nada a la pregunta

Comment: Si, pero aporta mi progreso en la busqueda asi animo a dar mas opciones